# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment, pandas operation

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to grab some finanical data off a financial website. I wanna manipulate `df['__this value__']`. I did some research myself, and I understand the error fine, but I really have no idea how to fix it. This is how my code is like:

```
import requests
import bs4
import os
import pandas as pd


def worker_names(code=600110):

    ......

    df = pd.DataFrame({'class': name_list})
    worker_years(df)


def worker_years(df, code=600110, years=None):

    if years is None:
        years = ['2019', '2018', '2017', '2016']
        url = 'http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/dbfx_'\
              + str(code) + '.html?date='\
              + str(years) + '-12-31,'\
              + str(years) + '-09-30#01c08'

        ......

        df['{}-12-31'.format(years)] = number_list  # this is where the problem is
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['class'], keep=False)
        df.to_csv(".\\__fundamentals__\\{:0>6}.csv".format(code),
                  index=False, encoding='GBK')
        print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.unicode.ambiguous_as_wide', True)
    pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

    fundamental_path = '.\\__fundamentals__'
    stock_path = '.\\__stock__'

    worker_names(code=600110)
```

Is there any ways that I can work around? please help! THX ALL!

Comment: where did you declare you str var in your code ? and why you are using is as a function ? str(code) ... ? please give us more data about str var where you declared it ...  is it a function or just an array ?

Comment: I declared it where ```years = ['2019', '2018', '2017', '2016']```, I wanna name my df[col] with years, respectively. @ZINEMahmoud

Comment: your str(code) str(year) ... make no sense to your code ? ....  what is str in your code ? that was my question ? is it a function or a var ?  you can't just set it without defining it

Comment: 'str' is still undefined sir

Comment: It seems I am not quite getting it by 'str' is not defined. my coding ability is still pretty amatuer. can you give me some hints by that? @ZINEMahmoud

Comment: do you mean i should have something like this? ```for i, year in enumerate(years, 1)```? @ZINEMahmoud

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213917/discussion-between-zine-mahmoud-and-mike-leigh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your codes `df['{}-12-31'.format(years)] = number_list` demostrate a very good example of `you can't make 2 variables on both side of the equation.` Try this:

```
df_year = pd.DataFrame({'{}'.format(year): number_list})
df = pd.concat([df, df_year], axis=1)
```

work around with dataframe, there are many different ways to get the same result.